# Getting a model name

Tags: ember.js

I have an instance `resource`, and I don't know if it's a `User` or `Organization` or `Comment` or what. Is there a way to get the name of the resource's model, something like `resource.get('modelName')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out the constructor, I'm not completely sure if that's what you're looking for.

```
 resource.constructor
```

Comment: It's ugly, but I'm able to get the formatting I need with `String(resource.constructor).replace('App.', '').underscore()`.

Comment: Depending on the resource and the usecase, a more Ember-y way to do this would be resource.constructor.typeKey

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to check if `resource` is an instance of which object.

```
var resource = App.Organization.create({});

console.log(resource instanceof App.User);          // false
console.log(resource instanceof App.Organization);  // true
console.log(resource instanceof App.Comment);       // false
```

Comment: Not quite the approach I was looking for here, but this technique will come in useful later. Thanks for the tip.